# Dynamic value as HTML for the custom field in Docusign Template

Tags: templates, dynamic, docusignapi

I am having one scenario where I want to replace my custom field value in a DocuSign template with the HTML table.

When I am trying to do this, it is just showing me the tags as it is. I know PDF will not convert the HTML but do you have any option how I can manage this scenario.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to achieve, do you want to pass HTML Table as DS Tab value?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot yet have dynamic HTML show in the envelope. That may be a later feature. However, you can get dynamic data in the tabs that is updated when the envelope is created.